# RestAssured alternative for Java that allows for customization of TLS version?

Tags: java, rest, unit-tests

Currently RestAssured doesn't have a way to force a TLS version when making a request without using a deprecated library (`SslSocketFactory`), are there any other REST API testing frameworks that could allow for this customization?